# Angular filter starts after two letters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

Say you have the following html:

```
<input ng-model="searchUser" placeholder="search user"/>
<ul class="list-group pull-in">
    <li class="list-group-item fade-in-left-big" style="cursor: pointer"
        ng-repeat="user in users | filter:searchUser" ng-click="addToUser(user)"
        ng-hide="members.indexOf(user) >= 0;">
        <a class="pull-left thumb-sm avatar m-r">
            <img src="{{user.image_path.length == 0 ? 'img/AdamProfil.png' : user.image_path}}"
                 alt="" class="img-circle">
        </a>

        <div class="clear">
            <div><a href="">{{user.fullname || user.username}}</a></div>
            <small class="text-muted">{{user.title.name}}</small>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now the as you can see the input in the first line allows you to search (`filter`) through the list.

This works fine however there is a strange annyoing feature attached to it. It doesn't start filtering untill two letters or more has been typed in.

Can anyone explain this behavior and maybe a way to remove it so it searches as soon as you type something.

Comment: Shouldn't be happening, can you reproduce on fiddle/plunker?

Comment: The code you are posted can't behave like you are describing. I assume that you have some other code that influence. So you didn't post complete example sufficient for replication of the issue.

Comment: @dfsq http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19592/ but apprently here it works as intended S:

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Maybe `ng-hide="members.indexOf(user) >= 0;"` is messing around with it, though I can't see how.

Comment: Filter searchs all fields by default - so if user has some string code like 'aec0982bcc' then bc will match this user - may be this cause issue?